# Insert data on MySQL Database c# .NET

Tags: c#, mysql

I would like to enter data into my database when a user clicks the button. The problem should be solved with this code:

```
MySqlCommand com = connection.CreateCommand();
com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('" + txt_usrn.Text + "', '" + txt_pssw.Text+ "')");
```

But I'm noticing (from my phpmyadmin panel) that clicking on the button doesn't insert anything. I honestly don't know why, do you know why? I leave you my complete code:

```
namespace sharetru
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn(

            int nLeft,
            int nTop,
            int nRight,
            int nBottom,
            int nWidthEllipse,
            int nHeightEllipse

            );

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();         
        }

        //mysql
        MySqlConnection connection;
        
        
        Point lastpoint;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn_accedi.Region = Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, btn_accedi.Width, btn_accedi.Height, 7, 7));
            btn_accedi.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 149, 246);
         
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(250, 250, 250);
            try
            {
                connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=sql7.freemysqlhosting.net; Port=3306; Database=sql7389377; Uid=sql7389377; Pwd=*********; ");
                connection.Open();
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    label1.Text = "Connected";
                    label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = "Not Connected";
                    label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

           
        }
                                              
        private void btn_accedi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlCommand com = connection.CreateCommand();
            com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('" + txt_usrn.Text + "', '" + txt_pssw.Text+ "')");
            lbl_fkeerr.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to execute the query. Also you forgot that `MySqlCommand` is `IDisposable`, so you should use `using` block.

See corrected code:

```
private void btn_accedi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(MySqlCommand com = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('" + txt_usrn.Text + "', '" + txt_pssw.Text+ "')");
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lbl_fkeerr.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

**Further remarks**

The code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack - due to string concatenation. You should use `Parameters` property to supply parameters to query.

Also, `MySqlConnection` also is `IDisposable` so make sure you correctly **dispose of this object as well**.